# Copy multiple records with a master-details relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am facing a problem in SQL Server with copying multiple related tables at a time.

I have two tables. One is `StageDetails` and another is `StageDetailsItem`.

The `StageDetails` table contains three rows and the `StageDetailsItem` table contains fifteen rows.
Each row from `StageDetails` has five rows in `StageDetailsItem`.

There is a master-details relationship between `StateDetails` and `StageDetailsItems`.

I want to copy three `StageDetails` records and fifteen `StageDetailsItem` records in one shot 
into the same tables and I want to change `StageDetailID` of `StageDetailsItem` 
when `StageDetailsItem` is being inserted.

I don't want to use an explicit loop, like `CURSOR`, `WHILE`, etc.

Here is the DDL script for `StageDetails` and `StageDetailsItem`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StageDetail](
    [StageDetailID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StageNUmber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [TypeOfStage] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Distance] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_StageDetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [StageDetailID] ASC
) WITH (
    PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StageDetailItem](
    [StageDetailItemID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StageDetailID] [int] NULL,
    [Road] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [CostPer] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_StageDetailItem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [StageDetailItemID] ASC
) WITH (
    PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StageDetailItem] WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_StageDetailItem_StageDetail] FOREIGN KEY([StageDetailID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[StageDetail] ([StageDetailID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StageDetailItem] 
CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_StageDetailItem_StageDetail]
GO
```

I can easily copy records from one table like this:

```
INSERT INTO EventDetailsEventType(EventID, EventTypeID)
SELECT @EventDetailsID, EventTypeID 
FROM EventDetailsEventType 
WHERE EventID = @ParentEventID;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Is it just the whole contents of these tables to be copied?

Comment: Are you copying the content out and reinserting it?

Comment: Are you copying it to another table if so what is the destination table structure

Comment: @bowlturner, yes i want to reinsert.

Comment: @NoDisplayName, source and destination table are same but they will maintain their repationship. I want to reinsert.

Comment: @Paddy, Hey I have no idea about this that's why i did not try this. but i have done this work into one table. can i give you that code?

Comment: what is the reason behind doing this why do you want to duplicate records.

Comment: @NoDisplayName, The user will copy the whole Stage, after copying this he will change little bit. Actually not duplicate records. StageDetailsID and StageDetailsItemID will be change because those will be identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution described here will work correctly in multi-user environment.

I'd use [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) with `OUTPUT` clause.

`MERGE` can `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` rows. 
In this case we need only `INSERT`.

`1=0` is always false, so the `NOT MATCHED BY TARGET` part is always executed. 
In general, there could be other branches, see docs. 
`WHEN MATCHED` is usually used to `UPDATE`; 
`WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` is usually used to `DELETE`, but we don't need them here.

This convoluted form of `MERGE` is equivalent to simple `INSERT`, 
but unlike simple `INSERT` its `OUTPUT` clause allows to refer to the columns that we need. 
It allows to retrieve columns from both source and destination tables thus saving a mapping 
between old existing IDs and new IDs generated by `IDENTITY`.

**Sample data**

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[StageDetail]
    ([StageNUmber]
    ,[TypeOfStage]
    ,[Distance])
VALUES
    ('sn01','t1','D1'),
    ('sn02','t2','D2'),
    ('sn03','t3','D3');

INSERT INTO [dbo].[StageDetailItem]
    ([StageDetailID]
    ,[Road]
    ,[CostPer])
VALUES
    (1,'r1_1','C11'),
    (1,'r1_2','C12'),
    (1,'r1_3','C13'),
    (1,'r1_4','C14'),
    (1,'r1_5','C15'),

    (2,'r2_1','C16'),
    (2,'r2_2','C17'),
    (2,'r2_3','C18'),
    (2,'r2_4','C19'),
    (2,'r2_5','C20'),

    (3,'r3_1','C21'),
    (3,'r3_2','C22'),
    (3,'r3_3','C23'),
    (3,'r3_4','C24'),
    (3,'r3_5','C25');
```

**Query**

Declare a table variable (or temp table) to hold the mapping between old and new IDs.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(OldStageDetailID int, NewStageDetailID int);
```

At first make a copy of rows from `StageDetail` table remembering the mapping of IDs in the table variable.

```
MERGE INTO [dbo].[StageDetail]
USING
(
    SELECT [StageDetailID],[StageNUmber],[TypeOfStage],[Distance]
    FROM [dbo].[StageDetail]
) AS Src
ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT ([StageNUmber],[TypeOfStage],[Distance])
VALUES
    (Src.[StageNUmber]
    ,Src.[TypeOfStage]
    ,Src.[Distance])
OUTPUT 
    Src.[StageDetailID] AS OldStageDetailID
    ,inserted.[StageDetailID] AS NewStageDetailID
INTO @T(OldStageDetailID, NewStageDetailID)
;
```

Then copy rows from `StageDetailItem` using new `StageDetailIDs`.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[StageDetailItem]
    ([StageDetailID]
    ,[Road]
    ,[CostPer])
SELECT
    T.[NewStageDetailID]
    ,[dbo].[StageDetailItem].[Road]
    ,[dbo].[StageDetailItem].[CostPer]
FROM
    [dbo].[StageDetailItem]
    INNER JOIN @T AS T ON T.OldStageDetailID = [dbo].[StageDetailItem].StageDetailID
;
```

**Result**

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StageDetail]

+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------+
| StageDetailID | StageNUmber | TypeOfStage | Distance |
+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------+
|             1 | sn01        | t1          | D1       |
|             2 | sn02        | t2          | D2       |
|             3 | sn03        | t3          | D3       |
|             4 | sn01        | t1          | D1       |
|             5 | sn02        | t2          | D2       |
|             6 | sn03        | t3          | D3       |
+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------+
```

.

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StageDetailItem]

+-------------------+---------------+------+---------+
| StageDetailItemID | StageDetailID | Road | CostPer |
+-------------------+---------------+------+---------+
|                 1 |             1 | r1_1 | C11     |
|                 2 |             1 | r1_2 | C12     |
|                 3 |             1 | r1_3 | C13     |
|                 4 |             1 | r1_4 | C14     |
|                 5 |             1 | r1_5 | C15     |
|                 6 |             2 | r2_1 | C16     |
|                 7 |             2 | r2_2 | C17     |
|                 8 |             2 | r2_3 | C18     |
|                 9 |             2 | r2_4 | C19     |
|                10 |             2 | r2_5 | C20     |
|                11 |             3 | r3_1 | C21     |
|                12 |             3 | r3_2 | C22     |
|                13 |             3 | r3_3 | C23     |
|                14 |             3 | r3_4 | C24     |
|                15 |             3 | r3_5 | C25     |
|                16 |             4 | r1_1 | C11     |
|                17 |             4 | r1_2 | C12     |
|                18 |             4 | r1_3 | C13     |
|                19 |             4 | r1_4 | C14     |
|                20 |             4 | r1_5 | C15     |
|                21 |             5 | r2_1 | C16     |
|                22 |             5 | r2_2 | C17     |
|                23 |             5 | r2_3 | C18     |
|                24 |             5 | r2_4 | C19     |
|                25 |             5 | r2_5 | C20     |
|                26 |             6 | r3_1 | C21     |
|                27 |             6 | r3_2 | C22     |
|                28 |             6 | r3_3 | C23     |
|                29 |             6 | r3_4 | C24     |
|                30 |             6 | r3_5 | C25     |
+-------------------+---------------+------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks your reply. after checking it i will knock you.