# How pull data from 2 tables that have Uniqueidentifier's as PK's and populate the data into 2 new tables that have AutoIncremented ID's as PK's?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a few tables that contain ID's that are of type GUID, pretty much every table is using GUID's instead of incremented IDs, but thats neither here nor their, just a scope of what I am dealing with.

So I have a table called
MaterialType and MaterialSubType

the MaterialType is built as the following

```
MaterialTypeID (PK, Uniqueidentifier, not null)
MaterialType (varchar(40), not null)
Code (varchar(100), not null)
EnabledInd (tinyint, not null)
```

The MaterialSubType is built as follows

```
MaterialSubTypeID (PK, Uniqueidentifier, not null)
MaterialTypeID (PK, Uniqueidentifier, not null)
MaterialSubType (varchar(40), not null)
Code (varchar(100), not null)
EnabledInd (tinyint, not null)
```

The problem I am running into is that I have two updated tables that are pretty much identical, other than the fact is that I am using autoincremented ID's, I need to figure out how to query the data from the original tables and insert the data into the new tables.

I know I can do an "insert into select" to the tables, but that doesn't (at least to my knowledge) help me because I need to have a foreign key in the MaterialSubType to the MaterialType.

So I am not sure how this should be done or how to do it, reason being is that I am not an expert with SQL or a DBA.

Comment: I guess the FK is on column `MaterialTypeID`? Please state explicitly so no assumptions are made. Do you need to do this regularly or is it a one off? are both tables updated? Does it need to be updated back the other way if so? The basic approach is to insert new records in `MaterialType` that generate new ID's, but you need to preserve the original GUID so you can use that to 'back reference' and assign the FK's in `MaterialSubType` before inserting them. You'd do this either through a staging table or by permanently adding a 'source reference key'  column in your target table.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, to answer your questions... Yes the FK column is the MaterialTypeID, Its a one off, never to happen again. The database that I am working with has all PK's as uniqueIdentifiers and I am changing things around to use Auto Incremented ID's.
What I have started trying is creating temp tables, passing the info needed and then using a where statement, if that makes sense?

Comment: Yep makes perfect sense. I'll pose an answer

Comment: I'd use `OUTPUT` clause of the `MERGE` statement to establish a mapping between old and new IDs as I've shown in the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27498204/4116017) to a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

Again I'm making assumptions:

- The `code` is the universal identifier that you're using to identify new records in both tables
- The autoincrement identity values are on
  `MaterialType.MaterialTypeID` and `MaterialSubType.MaterialSubTypeID`
  (though it doesn't really make sense if you have a PK on two columns
  when only one would be required in this case)
- The databases are on the same SQL Server

First add new records to `MaterialType` so we can generate a key:

```
INSERT INTO TargetDB..MaterialType (MaterialType, Code, EnabledInd)
SELECT MaterialType, Code, EnabledInd
FROM SourceDB..MaterialType SRC
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM  TGT
  WHERE TGT.Code = SRC.Code
)
```

Now add new records to `MaterialSubType`. To get the target FK value we need to first look up the code value in the source, then use that to lookup the correct FK value in the target.

I strongly suggest you first just run the select without the insert and test some records manually.

```
INSERT INTO TargetDB..MaterialSubType (
MaterialTypeID,
MaterialSubType,
Code,
EnabledInd
)
SELECT
-- We get this FK value by first looking up the code in the source 
-- then using that to look up the FK in the target
MT.MaterialTypeID,
SRC.MaterialSubType,
SRC.Code,
SRC.EnabledInd
FROM 
SourceDB..MaterialSubType SRC
INNER JOIN
-- Join to source lookup to find the code
SourceDB..MaterialType FK
ON SRC.MaterialTypeID = FK.MaterialTypeID
-- Now we have the source code, look up the target to get the target FK
INNER JOIN
TargetDB..MaterialType MT
ON FK.Code = MT.Code
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM TargetDB..MaterialSubType TGT
    SRC.Code = TGT.Code
    )
```

There might be some errors here. If there are, and you would like them fixed please also confirm my assumptions.