# Inserting into TWO tables from one table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to insert into `TableB` and `TableC` from `TableA`. There are approximately 30 columns in Table A out of which let's say 10 goes to `TableB` and 20 goes to `TableC`.

The data has to go I believe row by row because. I have to insert one row in `TableB` which will generate `TableID` as a auto increment PK which is FK in `TableC`. I need the `TableID` to be inserted with rest of the columns into `TableC`.

Below is the code I am using. With this code, my `TableB` works fine and all the columns and rows are inserted in `TableC` except the `ID` is all same in `TableC`.

There are thousands of rows in `TableA`.

```
DECLARE @c BIGINT

INSERT INTO dbo.TableB (--TableBId - column value is auto-generated
                        FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, PhoneNumber,
                        CreatedBy, Created, Updatedby, Updated, IsActive)
    SELECT 
        MSFIRST, MSMI, MSLAST, MSPHONE, 
        9999, GETDATE(), 9999, GETDATE(), 1 
    FROM 
        TableA

SET @C = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableC] (ClientID, TableBId, SSN, 
                            CreatedBy, Created, UpdatedBy, Updated)
    SELECT  
        400, @C, MSSS, 
        9999, GETDATE(), 9999, (GETDATE()) 
    FROM 
        TableA
-- DROP table #tt


SELECT * FROM TableB
SELECT * FROM dbo.TableC
```

Comment: Is this a one time load or something that's going to reoccur? I ask, because your limitation of the auto increment TableBId could be worked around.

Comment: Is there no natural key? Which should be implemented as a unique constraint or unique index.

Comment: WEll, the `SET @C = SCOPE_IDENTITY()` of course will **only** retrieve the **last** `ID` inserted - so if your `INSERT` inserted 1000 rows, you only get back the **last** (1000th) generated ID - and then you're using that for each and every row you're inserting into `TableC` - so **of course** all the values for `TableBId` will be the same - since you really only have **ONE** `TableBId` value.......

Comment: It is possible to do it in an efficient set-based way using `OUTPUT` clause together with the `MERGE` statement. Here is one similar question [Cascade copy a row with all child rows and their child rows, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41595802/cascade-copy-a-row-with-all-child-rows-and-their-child-rows-etc)

Comment: This will be an ongoing process. We will be getting the files like that on a monthly basis. There is no natural key in TableA.